# Powershell regular expression syntax for matching exactly 6 characters that start with two letters at end of url

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have been trying to get a regular expression right for the powershell match command.
I am looping through all site collections in a web application (my sites have URLs SC followed by exactly 4 digits,  For example, SC0001, SC0002, SC0003, etc.)

I am matching on the $site.url and not the $site.title, the $site.title is a longer string that is the true title of the site.

I can match on "SC0" but I also get sites that are named SC0001backup and SC0001test.

```
$sites = Get-SPWebApplication https://<webapplication url> | Get-SPSite -Limit All
foreach($site in $sites) 
{     
    if ($site -match "SC0")

    {
        Write-Host $site.Url, $site.RootWeb.Title
    } 
}
```

I am trying to get the regular expression correct that will give me all sites that have exactly 6 characters starting with SCxxxx and I can't quite seem to get it correct.

Any regular expression gurus able to assist me with the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following: `/SC\d{4,}$`

I have added a `/` since you are doing the entire URL. I assumed you had parsed the string out. I have tested it against these

```
/SC0001
/SC0001backup
/SC0001test
/SC0002
/XZ0001derp
/badsiteSC0001
```

And it matched the first and  fourth only.

Comment: If I have SC0001, SC0002, SC0003, SC0001backup, SC0001test, XZ0001derp, I want it to match ONLY the first 3.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it. `^` matches the start of a string and `$` matches the end.

Comment: is the , after the 4 necessary?

Comment: No, I do that just as a habit I picked up.

Comment: Is my current edit acceptable? Technically you need the `^` as not having it would also match `somesiteSC0001`.

Comment: the actual url is https://domainname.com/sites/SC0001, so the ^ doesn't help me there. so I can use:   if ($site.url -match "https://domainname.com/sites/SC\d{4}$") to avoid that scenario that has somesiteSC0001 in it.

Comment: I added a `/`. You might want that just to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already got a great answer using regex, but you also could have parsed the string out to leave only what's remaining after the "SC", and tried to parse *that* as an integer.

Like

```
$shouldBeInteger = $site.Url.Substring($site.Url.LastIndexOf("/") + 3)

try
{
    $siteNumber = [System.Int32]::Parse($shouldBeInteger)
}
catch
{
    # oops, guess there were more than just numbers in that string
}
```